# Grails domain unit testing - mockFor()

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

This is the domain class:

```
class Registration {

  String email
  String generatedKey

  def beforeInsert = {
      String newToken = GlobalHelper.getRandomString()
      generatedKey = newToken
  }
}
```

and this is the relevant part of the unit test:

```
    def c = mockFor(GlobalHelper)
    c.demand.static.getRandomString {-> return "nestoABC" }
    c.createMock()
    reg.beforeInsert()
```

When running the test, I get this error:

---

No such property: GlobalHelper for class: RegistrationTests

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GlobalHelper for class: RegistrationTests
at RegistrationTests.testConstraints(RegistrationTests.groovy:57)

---

The GlobalHelper class is located in Groovy source folder, and the mentioned line 57 is the line with the mockFor() method.

Grails Testing docs were not very helpfull regarding this issue...

I know this would be easily solved using integration tests, but I think it should also work this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you import GlobalHelper class?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Using+MockFor+and+StubFor#UsingMockForandStubFor-MockForTests) document, mocking static methods doesn't currently work.

Comment: unfortunately, I think this is not the issue here. The exception happens already on this line:

def c = mockFor(GlobalHelper)

Static method isn't even mentioned yet in in this part of code...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Grails are you using?

Using Grails 1.1.1 the following test works with your `Registration` domain as listed above.  This should run on Grails 1.1+ and Grails 1.0.x with the testing plugin.

You'll want to make sure that your unit test extends `GrailsUnitTestCase`.  I've made that mistake a number of times.

```
import grails.test.*

class RegistrationTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    void testBeforeInsert() {
        def reg = new Registration()
        reg.generatedKey = "preBeforeInsert"
        String randomString = "nestoABC"

        def c = mockFor(GlobalHelper)
        c.demand.static.getRandomString {-> return randomString }

        assertNotSame(reg.generatedKey, randomString)
        reg.beforeInsert()
        assertSame(reg.generatedKey, randomString)

        c.verify() //Verify the demands
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Grails 1.1, so this might be the issue. GrailsUnitTestCase is extended, but something is broken. Grails 1.1.1 is currently not an option, so I did this and it's working:

GlobalHelper.metaClass.static.getRandomString = { -> return "nestoABC" }

Comment: Gotta be careful when adding methods to the metaClass.  You'll want to make sure you clean them up or you might run into issues with other tests.

Does my test work if you run it within your test suite?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and resolved it by fully qualifying the Class name of the class to be mocked. So for your example:

```
def c = mockFor(GlobalHelper)
```

would become

```
def c = mockFor(com.example.fully.qualified.GlobalHelper)
```